# Replace a JSON value of a property in several JObjects

Tags: c#, json, linq, visual-studio-2012, json.net

I have a JSON file I'm reading from text and parsing it into JObject using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq. The JSON file looks like this:

```
{  
   "EntityTypeDto":[  
      {  
         "EntityType":"Grade",
         "Language":"ES"
      },
      {  
         "EntityType":"ApplicationType",
         "Language":"ES"
      },
      {  
         "EntityType":"Borough",
         "Language":"ES"
      }

   ]
}
```

Using the Newtonsoft library, are there any methods I can leverage on JObject to replace the Language property of all the objects to another value? If not what would be another way to do this? This project is a console application in C#, VS 2012, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need Linq here to achieve what you need , Linq is for consult data, not for modify it. So you can just, eg, a `foreach` to iterate and modify the elements of the array:

```
JObject json= JObject.Parse(jsonString);
JArray entityTypeDtos= (JArray)json["EntityTypeDto"];
foreach(var e in entityTypeDtos)
{
  if(e["Language"] != null)
     e["Language"]="EN";
}
```

Comment: After I make those changes, how do I return it back to the JObject (for which you named "json") with the new values?

Comment: Debug and check `json` variable after execute the `foreach`, you will see the elements will be changed to `EN`

Comment: Json is hierarchical and strcutured like Xml, just much less verbose, that's why it is possible to enumerate and replace, since it suppose to be well formed

Comment: @octavioccl, you may need to check `e["Language"] != null`, to be sure before making a change. Since even W/o Language element in few elements it will be perfect Json

Comment: Well, that is true, but I always I left to the OP that kind of validations to focus only in the main problem, anyway thanks for the suggestion ;)

Comment: Sure Welcome :)

Comment: Ok a  typo when I tried your code:
`JObject json= JObject.Parse(json);`, both JObject and json data string have same variable name `json`

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing by the `Linq` tag you would like a `Linq` approach try this

```
string json = @"{  
   'EntityTypeDto':[  
      {  
         'EntityType':'Grade',
         'Language':'ES'
      },
      {  
         'EntityType':'ApplicationType',
         'Language':'ES'
      },
      {  
         'EntityType':'Borough',
         'Language':'ES'
      }
   ]
}";


JObject myjobj = JObject.Parse(json);

JArray EntityType = (JArray)myjobj["EntityTypeDto"];

(from eobj in EntityType 
where eobj["Language"]="ES"
select eobj).ForEach(x => x["Language"]="New Value");
```

Comment: Thanks for this, how would I convert back into the JObject after the Language value is updated?

Comment: @user3299379 `Foreach` is a method of `List<T>`, also you need to cast:`(string)eobj["Language"]="ES"`